# Google Search Assistant App browser on iPhone conflict with the bottom nav bar

Tags: ios, css, browser, position, fixed

I'm having an issue with the browser of the Google App on iPhone (known simply as "Google" in iTunes).

Background: on iPhone, both browsers (Google Search & Assistant and Safari) have a bottom nav-bar that appears/disappears as you scroll up and down a website page.

In any case, in many of my sites, I have a button in most pages, with position "fixed" to the bottom of the screen. In the Google browser, when I scroll up and down the page, this button appears/disappears and is replaced by the bottom nav-bar.

And when the bottom nav bar disappears and the button reappears, it is not clickable as it seems that there's an invisible layer that prevents it from happening. The "normal" behaviour in these cases seems to be for the bottom nav-bar to reappear. So, in fact, this button becomes "unclickable".

Now, when I try the same pages using Safari, the browser is "smart enough" to nudge the button up, keeping it clickable.

If you want to have a sense of this behaviour, you can find it in this page: https://www.avenuefive.com.

Why is this? Is this a bug of Google App? A feature that is not supported (fixed position)? Or something else altogether?